# undefined variable in codeigniter 3 view

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello there please help me am stuck on error: undefined variable query:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: users/all_users.php

Line Number: 14

here is my controller:
controller code for project

```
               <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_manager extends CI_Controller{

        function _construct(){
            parent::_construct();

            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('security');
            $this->load->model('Users_manager_model');
            $this->load->database();

        }

        public function index(){

            redirect('users/view_users');
        }

          public function view_users(){ 
            $data['query'] = $this->user_manager_model->get_all_users();
            $this->load->view(users/all_users, $data);
        }}
```

And here is my model

```
  <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_manager_model extends CI_Model{

    function construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_all_users(){

        return $this->db->get('users');

    }}
```

finally here is my view for my users

```
<?php if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) : ?>
<table table-bordered table-responsive style="margin-top: 20px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Employee No.</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Created</td>
        <td>Is Active</td>
        <td colspan="2">Actions</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) : ?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->emp_no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->dept; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("d-m-y", $row->cdate); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row->is_active ? 'Yes' : 'No'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo anchor('users/edit_user/'.$row->id, 'Edit'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo anchor('users/delete_user/'.$row->id, 'Delete'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: john i cant understand the answers here just pleas answer me according to my code

Comment: thank in advance #john

Comment: Probably just an oversight, but shouldn't ` $this->load->view(users/all_users, $data);` have quotes? As in, ` $this->load->view('users/all_users', $data);`

Comment: I just noticed your controller is named `User_manager` but you're redirecting to `users/view_users` in index(); Is there a route that redirects or is there a Users controller with a view_users method?